# Hide some items from JList Java

Tags: java, jlist

I'm trying to hide (not remove) some items from a JList Java, but I can't find the way.

The process I'm trying to realize is a list with JCheckbox and a search form (textfield). When the user fire some text I filter the list, but I need to keep the state of the checkbox, so I can't remove the item, but only hide or show it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Separate your data from your UI, then you can create a filter on your data so the UI will only see those items.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user fire some text I filter the list,

JList does not support filtering.

You can use a single column `JTable`. `JTable` does support filtering.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information and working examples.